# Excel UDF that returns `Static` value

Tags: excel, vba

I have written an UDF that simply takes a lot of time to calculate. The formula actually calcualtes multiple values, so as one of the parameters that user needs to enter is which one of the values should formula output.

So my question is "is it possible for the UDF to remeber caculations it has done while calculating in another cell?" I guess that would be similar behavior to `Static` variables.

Here is pseudo code of my formula:

```
Public Function UDF(repeat as integer, return as integer) as Integer
    Dim array(1 To 2) as Integer

    array(1) = 2 * repeat
    array(2) = 3 * repeat

    UDF = array(return)
End
```

And here is a sample sheet inplementing this formula

```
    A         | B
1   "Repeats" | 2,000,000
2   "UDF #1"  | =UDF(B1,1) 
3   "UDF #2"  | =UDF(B1,2)
```

As you can see in this example the two `UDFs` only vary with return type, and once the first one calcualtes the second "could" use that calcuation instead of recalculating from scratch.

Comment: You can create global objects that store information.  You could then possibly index that info in a way to cache calculations.  You will have a bear of a time though working this into Excel's own cached calculations and will likely create inconsistencies in the data.

Comment: You could have the formula output an array and use an array formula to get both results into the spreadsheet.  This requires the outputs be next to each other in the spreadsheet.